# how to remove action and controller from url in rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my `link_to`

```
<%= link_to sub_category.name, controller: :posts, action: :product, id: "#{sub_category.slug}-#{sub_category.id}" %>
```

Which is pointing to the url

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/product/fifith-category-s-sub-category-2
```

I need the url as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/fifith-category-s-sub-category-2
```

How can i do it.

my route.rb

```
resources :posts
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:get,:post]
```

Comment: Please paste your config/routes.rb content.

Comment: @MarekLipka included my `route.rb` can you please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what @MarekLipka suggests is correct but defining your routes like this will take up all the single level namespace in your app i.e. "/anything" will route by default to `posts#product`.

I recommended using some form of identifier to figure out which routes should go to `posts#product`. What will work for you  depends on why you want to do this. Couple of options are:

Use a short namespace:

```
scope '/pp' do 
    get ':id', to: 'posts#product
end
# "/pp/:id" routes to 'posts/product'
# pp is a random short name I picked, it could be anything

# link
<%= link_to sub_category.name, "pp/#{sub_category.slug}-#{sub_category.id}" %>
```

Use a constraint:

```
get ':id', to: 'posts#product`, constraints: { :id => /sub\-category/ }
# only id's with 'sub-cateogry' route to 'posts/product'

# link (assuming that sub_category.slug has 'sub-category' words in it)
<%= link_to sub_category.name, "#{sub_category.slug}-#{sub_category.id}" %>
```

Comment: what does `/pp` means and how to use it in link_to

Comment: @Seting updated the answer, what do you mean by "but url as my old url" ?

Comment: sorry typed wrongly. Now link is pointing to `localhost:3000/somethins-test-1` but getting `routing error` on clicking link

Comment: For second option to work `sub-cateogry` words should be in the url. If that is not the case then go with Marek's answer

Comment: first method also throwing exception `no route found`

Answer (score 0):

If you want path `/:id` match your `posts#product`, you should have something like this in your routes:

```
resources :posts
match ':id', to: 'posts#product`, via: :get
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: working good but i need one clarification. If i have `id` for `other_controller#other_action` what will happen?

Comment: @Seting ':controller/:action/:id' URL will be generated.

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand can you please brief it